# WCF - Consuming SOAP Service Over HTTPS - Request Timeout

Tags: wcf, soap, ssl, https, wcf-security

I have a WPF application, and I'm using WCF to consume a php webservice over Https, I've created a self-singed certificate on the server to test it and configured the client to use this certificate, but an exception appeared and tell me that I need to pass the client certificate also.

Actually I just want to secure the transmitted message, I don't need to authenticate the client, so how could I disable the client authentication.

I'm using security model "Transport" with clientCredentialType "Certificate" and .Net 3.5.

thanks in advance for opinions..

**UPDATE**

As I've mentioned, I don't need the service to verify the identity of the client so I have used [Transport Security with an Anonymous Client](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms729789%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) instead of [Transport Security With Certificate Authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731074.aspx), the following is the client configurations:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="bindingName" closeTimeout="00:0:04"
       openTimeout="00:00:04" receiveTimeout="00:00:04" sendTimeout="00:00:04"
       allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
       messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8"
       useDefaultWebProxy="true">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"> 
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint address="https://myServer/myApp/myWebService"
    binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="bindingName"
    contract="xx.yy" name="zz">
  </endpoint>
</client>
```

**Now the issue is**: when I called the service a timeout error appears "The HTTP request to {My Service URL} has exceeded the allotted timeout".

**Additional Info**: The service worked fine over HTTP, the issues appear only when I moved to the HTTPS, and I can see the service WSDL if I open it through the internet browser, but the browse told me that there are insecure resources and I should enforce it to show me all resources in order to see the WSDL.

Comment: It seems your question has nothing to do with WPF, so I retaged it to wcf-security

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably your issue is:

> // Create the endpoint address. **Note that the machine name** 
>  //
>   **must match the subject or DNS field of the X.509 certificate**
>  //
>   used to authenticate the service.

So review your client config, and check certificate section `findValue` attribute to match you certificate's one.

Like

```
<clientCertificate findValue="contoso.com"
   storeLocation="CurrentUser"
   storeName="My"
   x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" />
```

See more about [Transport Security with Certificate Authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731074.aspx).

Comment: thank you very much @evgenyl, you've guided me to use the right security model that best fits my needs, but now a new issue appeared, would you plz check my update to see if I missing something else.

Comment: did your service code took more then 4 sec? try to enlarge send and receive timouts (lets say a minute?), as well as open timeout (30 seconds?). Also, if the post was useful, consider to mark it as an answer :)

Comment: unfortunately this doesn't help ..
when I disconnect from the network, it tells me that there is no endpoint listening, this means that the server itself is discovered by the client, but a failure may be happened during the communications.
could using a self-signed certificate cause such problems?

Comment: finally I've figured out the problem, it was in the configuration of the Apache server, especially in the virtual host that I configured to listen to the SSL port, I set the host name as "localhost" instead of the actual host name.
However, thanks alot @evgenyl for your guidance :)